# Do I HAVE to override GetHashCode and Equals in new Classes?

Tags: .net

Okay, so if I override Equals, I need to override GetHashCode and vice versa.

But I just wonder: Should I always override these two in any class? Especially if I know that I will use them in a Dictionary or similar collections? While this is [fairly straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416), it's still an extra work for every class.

Is the System.Object implementation bad enough to worry about this?

Edit: Can you detail a bit more what is Value and Reference equality? So if I have two strings (s1 and s2) that are both "test", they are value equal, but since they are two different strings, they are not reference-equal? Ok, for strings it's a no-brainer, but what are the common situations where you would want Reference or Value Equality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you only need to override them if you need value equality semantics. The System.Object implementation isn't 'bad', it just only does a reference check (which is all an implementation at that level can do).

In short: If you need some sort of value based equality (equality based on properties of the class), then yes, override away. Otherwise, it should be more than fine already.

**EDIT:**
You only **need** to override them in the case above. If you override one, you do need to override both for the obvious reasons (they need to be consistent, etc). You *can* override them on every class for other reasons noted in other answers (like performance in algorithms that use the hash value, ie. `Dictionary` keys, etc), but you don't need to, the default `System.Object` implementation will work correctly.

**EDIT 2:**
More information requested, so here goes. Consider the following pseudo-class:

```
public class User {
    private int _id;
    private string _username;
    public string Username { get {return _username;}};
    // [snip] Whatever other properties we might like to have.

    public User(string username) {
        // Initialise our user from a database, or whatever.
    }
}
```

As it stands, the following code, might seem intuitive:

```
User foo = new User("me");
User bar = new User("me");
User baz = foo;

if (foo.Equals(bar)) {
    Console.WriteLine("1: Success!");
}
if (foo.Equals(baz)) {
    Console.WriteLine("2: Success!");
}
```

But it will only print out:

> 2: Success

Why? `foo` and `bar` are two seperate instances of the class, and have separate references. A reference is like a pointer in C/C++. foo and baz are the same reference because one was assigned from the other. They all have the same *value* though, the user called "me". A sample implementation of a value based `.Equals` implementation might be:

```
partial class User {
    public override bool Equals(object b) {
        if (b == null) return false;
        if (b.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;

        // Now the heavy lifting
        User other = (User)b;
        if (other._id == this._id) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

See how it checks against part of the class's properties to determine equality? That's value equality at work. Reference equality would just be a simple `this == b` check.

Answer (score 3):

The two methods should be *consistent*.  In other words, if two objects are *equal*, then each should return the same *hash code*.  This is particularly important in hashed collections.  To find an object that matches object X in a hashed container, the container will only test those items for equality that have the same hash code as X.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you want Value semantics. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(VS.71).aspx):

> For some kinds of objects, it is
>   desirable to have Equals test for
>   value equality instead of referential
>   equality. Such implementations of
>   Equals return true if the two objects
>   have the same value, even if they are
>   not the same instance. The definition
>   of what constitutes an object's value
>   is up to the implementer of the type,
>   but it is typically some or all of the
>   data stored in the instance variables
>   of the object. For example, the value
>   of a string is based on the characters
>   of the string; the Equals method of
>   the String class returns true for any
>   two instances of a string that contain
>   exactly the same characters in the
>   same order.